# online acquisition

Tags: phrase-usage

I hired a freelancer who is a native speaker to improve my writing. This is his version. Does "online acquisition" sound natural?

> Not all physical shops will be replaced by online platforms because
> their environments offer customers experiences and products more
> suited **to in-person purchase than to online acquisition**.

I think he might want to avoid repeating "purchase". Does this work?

> Not all physical shops will be replaced by online platforms because
> their environments offer customers experiences and products more
> suited **to in-person than to online purchase**.

Comment: No, yours is not an improvement. But the first is also unnecessarily wordy.   **Physical** is redundant and a poor modifier of shops** You could greatly simplify your message.  **Not all shops/stores (will) offer online purchases because customers often prefer the experience and advantages of shopping in person.**

Comment: @RonaldSole, thank you very much for your comments. I don't understand "online acquisition"? So it can mean "shopping online"?

Comment: 'Acquisition' means either 'act of acquiring', or something that is acquired. So: *"He was dedicated to the acquisition of fine art"*, or *"her latest acquisition was a pencil sketch"*. And, yes, it does mean 'shopping on-line'.

Comment: Yes, the way this is written, it sounds exactly like he wanted to avoid repeating the word purchase. Your version is definitely better. So I strongly disagree with @RonaldSole on this point, though I agree with him that neither version is particularly good.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your comments. @cruthers, in my version, do I need to repeat "to": "suited to in-person than **to** online purchase" or "suited to in-person than online purchase"

Comment: Definitely don't need to repeat "to." I think I like it better without the repeat, but I don't feel strongly about it.